# Cheers to the Weekend!

Tags: riddle, rhyme

With a four day weekend coming up due to Labor Day; I've decided to write a riddle about my weekend plans. Can you guess what I'll be doing to celebrate this mini-vacation?

> Lighters and Wires,
>
> Cameras and Fires,
>
> Bourbon, Whiskey, and Scotch.
>
> Racers and Chasers,
>
> Lemons for Spacers,
>
> Cards, Bikinis, and Ponds.

I know this is too easy, but its a requirement for a surprise next week! Good luck to you all, and if your weekend starts today, then have a great weekend!

---

**Note**: To clarify the desired answer and prevent those *"I thought it might be this..."* answers, I'm looking for a single phrase in which all of the above are included. For example, a bad answer would be:

> You'll be getting drunk, playing cards, swimming, and burning things.

Comment: Instead of game night, game weekend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer:

> Looks like the answer is **Pool Party**. Alcohol, bikinis, ponds (pool), cards, etc. Also, Lemons are bitter, what seems to suggest Spacers are the bitter ones or anti-social that separate themselves from the group. Racers and Chasers might refer to a swimming competition.

Comment: A good answer indeed; it's more along the lines of a beach party but potato potato. :D